# Как удалить дубликаты в коллекций. Без использования Collection.sort Arrays.sort и Comparator. Можно пользоваться Comparable

Tags: java, list, коллекции, java-stream, treemap

Дается метод, который принимает лист продуктов. Мне нужно удалить дубликаты продуктов с одинаковым кодом. Попробывал реализовать через stream API,но остановился на настройку equals. Также пробовал с Set, но тоже не вышел результат

```
   public List<Product> distinct(List<Product> products) {

        return products.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


public class Product implements Comparable<Product>{
    private int code;
    private String title;


    public Product(int code, String title) {
        this.code = code;
        this.title = title;
    }


    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return code == product.code && Objects.equals(title, product.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(code, title);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "code=" + code +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
       return this.title.compareTo(o.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все у вас правильно работать должно

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product(1,"A"));
        products.add(new Product(1,"B"));
        products.add(new Product(1,"A"));
        products.add(new Product(2,"A"));

        System.out.println(distinct(products));

}


    public static List<Product> distinct(List<Product> products) {

        return products.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

вывод

```
[Product{code=1, title='A'}, Product{code=1, title='B'}, Product{code=2, title='A'}]
```

сравнение идет по методу Equals если нужно сравнить только по коду поменяйте на

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Product product = (Product) o;
    return code == product.code;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(code);
}
```

вывод после

```
[Product{code=1, title='A'}, Product{code=2, title='A'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, каким образом здесь можно применить `Comparable`, предназначенный для упорядочивания последовательности по возрастанию/убыванию, который к тому же в данной реализации сравнивает названия продуктов, а не коды, что позволяет отсортировать список/массив продуктов по названию в алфавитном порядке.

Также существующие реализации методов `hashCode` / `equals`, использующие оба поля класса `Product` не позволят обнаружить дубликаты *только по одному полю `code`*.

Для поиска дубликатов по одному полю требуется сгруппировать объекты в списке по этому полю, и тогда в зависимости от определения что считать "дубликатом" вернуть некий результат.

Например, для входных данных:

```
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
    new Product(1,"A"), new Product(1,"B"), new Product(1,"A"), new Product(2,"A")
);
```

после группировки по коду можно оставить:

- только `Product(2,"A")` - у него уникальный код,
- или же набор продуктов `Product(1,"A"), Product(2,"A")` - продукты с повторным кодом 1 были отброшены.

Здесь удобно применить коллекторы `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.toMap`, причём их можно параметризовать по геттеру/полю, по которому надо отфильтровать дубликаты `Product::getCode` или `Product::getTitle`

```java
public static <T> List<Product> distinct(List<Product> products, Function<Product, T> getter) {
    return new ArrayList<>(
            products.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        getter, p -> p, (p1, p2) -> p1, LinkedHashMap::new
                    ))
                    .values()
    );
}
```

```java
public static <T> List<Product> unique(List<Product> products, Function<Product, T> getter) {
    return products
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(getter))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(list -> list.size() == 1)
            .map(list -> list.get(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тесты:

```
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
        new Product(1,"A"), new Product(1,"B"),
        new Product(1,"A"), new Product(2,"A")
);

System.out.println("Distinct");
System.out.println(distinct(products, Product::getCode));
System.out.println(distinct(products, Product::getTitle));
System.out.println("Unique");
System.out.println(unique(products, Product::getCode));
System.out.println(unique(products, Product::getTitle));
```

Результаты:

```
Distinct
[Product{code=1, title='A'}, Product{code=2, title='A'}]
[Product{code=1, title='A'}, Product{code=1, title='B'}]
Unique
[Product{code=2, title='A'}]
[Product{code=1, title='B'}]
```